# Trying to convert duration to hours:minutes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a query that converts duration to hours : minutes. Everything works fine unless there are negative numbers. The following example should convert -.50 to -0:30 instead because I am using floor it converts to -1:30. Duration can be a mix of positive or negative numbers so I can't just multiply by -1. Here is my query

```
 select CAST(FLOOR(sum(-.50)) AS VARCHAR(3)) + ':' + RIGHT('00'+ 
  CAST(CAST(ROUND(( sum(-.50)- CAST(FLOOR(sum(-.50)) AS NUMERIC(8,4)) ) * 
 60.000,0) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Comment: what's the data type for the duration field? Or is is a calculation between two datetime fields?

Comment: It is a Numeric field

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use CASE for the solution ...

```
declare @value float = -0.5

select CASE WHEN @value > 0 THEN CAST(FLOOR(sum(@value)) AS VARCHAR(3)) 
            ELSE CAST(-FLOOR(sum(-@value)) AS VARCHAR(3)) END + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00'+ CAST(CAST(ROUND(( sum(@value)- CAST(FLOOR(sum(@value)) AS NUMERIC(8,4)) ) * 60.000,0) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Very similar solution without one expression is

```
select CAST(CASE WHEN @value > 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * FLOOR(sum(abs(@value))) AS VARCHAR(3)) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('00'+ CAST(CAST(ROUND(( sum(@value)- CAST(FLOOR(sum(@value)) AS NUMERIC(8,4)) ) * 60.000,0) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Comment: Try `-0.1`. Expected result: `-0:06`. Actual result: `-0:54`.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (dur decimal(8,2));
insert @t values ( -0.1), (2), (-2);

select case when sum(dur) < 0 then '-' else '' end +
       cast(abs(cast(60 * sum(dur) as int)) / 60  as varchar(10)) + ':' +
       right('00' + cast(abs(cast(60 * sum(dur) as int)) % 60 as varchar(2)), 2) as [hh:mm]
from @t;
```

Comment: Try `-0.1`. Expected result: `-0:06`. Actual result: `0:06`.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Yes you were right, I updated my answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you want to round durations to whole minutes; for example, a duration of `1.999` should be presented as `2:00` since 119.94 minutes rounds to 120, while `1.99` should be `1:59` since 119.4 minutes rounds to 119.

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(8, 2), 
            ROUND(ROUND(SUM(dur) * 60, 0) / 60, 0, 1) + 
            ROUND(SUM(dur) * 60, 0) % 60 / 100
        ), 
        '.', ':'
    )
```

Note the use of the truncation mode of `ROUND` in the hours part: `ROUND(number, 0, 1)` will truncate without regard for sign, unlike `FLOOR` or `CEILING`.